# Fixing Landsat 7 SLC-off in ENVI

Tags: landsat, envi, noise

I have a couple of Landsat 7 images and they all have striping as a result of the SLC failure. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to destripe the image using ENVI? I plan to use these images for NDVI analysis.

When I downloaded the data from GloVis, it also came with a Gap Mask folder...is that somehow related to the SLC-Off?

Answer (score 5):

Save this [Landsat Gapfill IDL Model](http://s3.amazonaws.com/nrcs-sgi/EvansModels/landsat_gapfill.sav) into the ENVI extensions folder:

- Application extensions folder - "C:\Program Files\Exelis\ENVI5[minor version]\extensions"
- User extensions folder - "C:\Users\[user name]\.idl\envi\extensions5_[minor version]".

E.g for ENVI 5.3 `"C:\Program Files\Exelis\ENVI53\extensions"` or `"C:\Users\MyUserName\.idl\envi\extensions5_3"`

In version 5 it will be under Extensions > Landsat_gapfill menu. It is fairly straightforward to understand the usage.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. Thanks for your solutions. The extension worked perfectly in my case. I was wondering if the algorithm was published in an article? also, do you know any program or lib with Python that can deal with gap-filling? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason you have to use Landsat 7, then you should be able to get coverage for the same area with either Landsat 5 or 8 and not worry about the SLC issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but I don't see why you need Landsat 7 and just use the Landsat 8. It will save you a lot of your time but..if you really want to use that Landsat 7.

you can go here [Filling the Gaps for Display](http://landsat.usgs.gov/filling_the_gaps_for_display.php)

Yes I agree with dblanchett.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, download the landsat_destripe file from exelis website. If you are using Envi 5.0, find the save_add folder in your installation destination and put it in there.

Fire up Envi Classic -> Basic tools -> Preprocessing -> General purpose utilities -> Landsat ETM+ Destriping.

Follow the GUI.

Answer (score -2):

I am not an expert in GIS, so I tried to find a workaround. 
My workaround was based on using a combination of ENVI and ArcGIS.

I overcame the problem in a bit of a different way and am sure there might be an even easier way of achieving the same result.
The SLC error problem and solution I came up with is here:

http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/4/9/2595

Hopefully it is of some use.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. Can you rework this (just click edit below your answer) to add the relevant  details here? That helps in cases such as when the link goes away or breaks, and makes the Q&A format read better.