# How to destripe the thermal band in SLC_off LandSat 7 ETM+ data?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat-7

I am working on a special study in one of my subject. My study would require me to extract land surface temperature each year for 2007-2014. Since LandSat 5 ceaseed to operate last 2011, my 2012-2014 data are from LandSat 7 with SLC_off. How will I destripe the thermal band? I have ENVI 5.1.

Comment: You can't create data that isn't there.

Comment: But you could interpolate it, resample up to a lower resolution. Or search for the data corrected by someone else, if it exists. In any event, you just have to note the problem with the data and what impacts it might have on the study.

Comment: This looks like it may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75151/fix-landsat-7-slc-off-in-envi because both have attracted an identical answer from one user.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really good website giving a summary of a couple techniques the writer tried and which one gave him the best results: https://blamannen.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/destripe-landsat-7-etm-some-thoughts/

The basic premise is what Chris W said. You're going to have to interpolate the missing values by using the lines above and below the missing data and then resample. It is going to cause your image to be smoothed so you may have to do some further processing to resharpen it. Depending on what this is for you may need to do a literature search and find someone else who's tackled this problem and follow their workflow in order to defend your methodology. You just need to find any paper that talks about how to destripe data though, any methods they use would also be used to destripe the thermal bands.

Comment: That blog page doesn't say which destriping tool from the EXELIS (previously ITTVIS) code library the author used, or (if it was the [Landsat Gapfill tool](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78449/2856)), which interpolation was attempted (single image triangulation or 2 image local histogram matching).  I haven't used the [Landsat Gapfill tool](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78449/2856) with L7 thermal bands, but have had very good results with the 2 image local histogram matching method with the RGBN bands.

Answer (score 1):

irst of all, download the landsat_destripe file from exelis website. If you are using Envi 5.0, find the save_add folder in your installation destination and put it in there.

Fire up Envi Classic -> Basic tools -> Preprocessing -> General purpose utilities -> Landsat ETM+ Destriping.

Follow the GUI.