# Landsat 7 SLC off gap-filling

Tags: landsat, landsat-7

Please suggest me how can I fill the gap of SLC off Landsat 7 data band 8 that is panchromatic band. Also suggest me is there any method to fill the gap of all other bands too.

Comment: Have you checked this question yet? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75151/fix-landsat-7-slc-off-in-envi/75164#75164

Comment: Yes . I have followed the processes mentioned in usgs site. But not working. I have envi 4.5, Erdas 9.3 and arcgis 9.3